# How to use class and data type in class diagram?

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

It might be a rookie question, but I want to draw a Class Diagram for my classes as below:

```
public class CustomerId
{
   ...
}

public class CustomerName
{
   ...
}

public class Customer
{
   public CustomerId CustomerId
   public CustomerName CustomerName
}
```

- How to draw those class into a Class Diagram?
- Should the CustomerId and CustomerName class have "datatype" tag?
- What relation should be use between classes?

Please help.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff657806.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a class diagram, you create three classes : CustomerId, CustomerName and Customer. You add two associations one on CustomerId with an end name cusotmerId with visibility private (with minus c) and one one CustomerName with an end name cusotmerName with visibility private .

Easy no ? :)
[image]

Comment: As a side note: the diagram uses lower case first char for attributes while the OP wrongly uses upper case (violates common convention). Your diagram uses private visibility instead of public like in the OP's code. And you should not mention that your first edit was incorrect :-)

Comment: I dealed with the first answer in case it has been seen? Java convention use lower case and i use this convention. Yes I use private because public for properties is often an error.

Comment: You should make it public, although public attributes are rarely a good idea. OPs code shows `public` so you should make it `+`. The case correction is fine, though :-)

Comment: @granier why the black circle? I'm used to seeing UML with just the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @granier's answer, but with [PlantUML](https://www.planttext.com/?text=AyxEp2j8B4hCLIWkgSn91P95cSabfRavN1cPAQaAgRa59PKAkQcvIQb5nLp9EOd5nGhEfSKb-RcfHPufQ09-YRcfQ49SC8Q2WcvAVdcUhfs2acuot82O8aCbPFFmgGQPZg8UR1q0) (and no black circles).

[image]

Comment: @ Fuhrmanator, the black circle is defined in the norm ... So you can use PlantUml but with your model custormerId and custormerName belong to the association and not to Customer (there are others questions about that here). The black circle defines who owns the end. I understood that "previously" the usage was "if there is an end name, it defines a variable". Version 2.5 tries to formalize that.